# Unreachable domain in AWS Route 53

Tags: networking, dns, routing, amazon-web-services, domain

I currently am having problems setting up a domain that i transferred to aws with route 53. Basically the architecture is pretty straight forward and the same procedure (as far as I can tell) worked for me in the past. Basically my setup looks like this

- Kubernetes Cluster with a load balancer
- Simple A entry in my Hosted Zone with an alias to that load balancer

I went through the steps as usually for this which would be

- transferred the Domain
- set up a Hosted Zone
- used the name servers from that zone to update the domain
- added my A and AAAA entry in the hosted zone with an alias to the load balancer
- SOA and NS entries were left as created

Now however when I am trying to access that domain I get DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Now I flushed my DNS cache so this should not be the problem. The previously hosted website from the previous provider is also not reachable anymore and whois also gives me the correct name servers from aws. They also definately match the one in the hosted zone.

I also activated another domain I am not using at the moment (which has some more entries for mail etc. but I guessed that that would still be ok for a test) and added the same entries for A and AAAA. This worked as expected and the domain was reachable.

Now I am pretty much out of ideas for the moment. Am I missing some entry or what else could be the problem? Would be great if someone had an idea

Answer (score 1):

OK so basically the setup was no problem. However if you run into the same issues as I also make sure to flush your routers DNS Cache. In my case this was the problem and after doing that my domain was reachable as expected.